# Which ruby frameworks are appropriate for internal services?

Tags: ruby, web-services, api, frameworks, sinatra

I'm making a web service that will only be used internally by other parts of my system. It will never have html rendering, and it will never be a publicly available API.

The two main candidates are [sinatra](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/) and [grape](https://github.com/intridea/grape). Are there any others I should consider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used both Grape and Sinatra for these types of services and both are fine.  I prefer Grape because:

- Automatic serialization is convenient (JSON by default)
- For RESTful services, 'resource' allows you to logically group resources

If you have an existing Rails application you can [mount Sinatra/Grape/WhateverRackBasedMiddleware](http://martinciu.com/2011/01/mounting-grape-api-inside-rails-application.html) you decide to use for your service.

Answer (score 1):

Theese could also be good candidates:

http://reneerb.com/

http://cramp.in/